# What are different heaps shown in !finalizequeue command

Tags: garbage-collection, windbg, finalizer, sos

When I run the `!finalizequeue` command on a dump file, it shows me different heap and the the total objects to be finalized under this. What are the different heaps like Heap 0, Heap 1 and so on in the result below? My understanding is that there would be one heap per process, is it correct?

```
0:000> !finalizequeue
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
Free-Threaded Interfaces to be released: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
------------------------------
Heap 0
generation 0 has 19 finalizable objects (41c7ed80->41c7edcc)
generation 1 has 19 finalizable objects (41c7ed34->41c7ed80)
generation 2 has 2283 finalizable objects (41c7c988->41c7ed34)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (41c7edcc->41c7edcc)
------------------------------
Heap 1
generation 0 has 101 finalizable objects (41ccc27c->41ccc410)
generation 1 has 25 finalizable objects (41ccc218->41ccc27c)
generation 2 has 2636 finalizable objects (41cc98e8->41ccc218)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (41ccc410->41ccc410)
------------------------------
Heap 2
generation 0 has 6 finalizable objects (41d4195c->41d41974)
generation 1 has 11 finalizable objects (41d41930->41d4195c)
generation 2 has 2328 finalizable objects (41d3f4d0->41d41930)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (41d41974->41d41974)
------------------------------
Heap 3
generation 0 has 21 finalizable objects (41c96188->41c961dc)
generation 1 has 16 finalizable objects (41c96148->41c96188)
generation 2 has 2584 finalizable objects (41c938e8->41c96148)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (41c961dc->41c961dc)
```

Answer (score 3):

Those are the GC heaps.  The GC in this process is running in server mode, which has one GC heap per processor.  The output is showing you the locations of the finalizable objects by generation and by heap.